# Laravel subquery join with where

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

so i am creating this kind of query

```
$data = App\SalesReport::with('company')->join(DB::RAW('(SELECT company_id, MAX(periods) AS max_periods FROM laporancu GROUP BY company_id) latest_report'),function($join){
    $join->on('salesreport.company_id','=','latest_report.company_id');
    $join->on('salesreport.periods','=','latest_report.max_periods');
})->FilterPaginateOrder();
```

and i want to put `where('periods','<=','2016-01-01')` but i have no idea where should i put it...

i tried to put it after `with('company')` and it won't returning salesreport at 2015 even thought i have some of them in database. So after experimenting i think i know why it is happening.

Because i have `$join->on('salesreport.periods','=','latest_report.max_periods');` and even thought `salesreport.periods` have periods less than equal 2016-01-01 but because of that join it will always match maximum periods from latest_report

so i think i should add those where clause when the query executing

```
DB::RAW('(SELECT company_id, MAX(periods) AS max_periods FROM laporancu GROUP BY company_id) latest_report')
```

but how? where should i put it?

**update:the exact sql statement (without company relationship)**

```
SELECT salesreport.* FROM salesreport
 INNER JOIN (SELECT company_id, MAX(periods) AS max_periods FROM salesreport GROUP BY company_id) AS latest_report
       ON salesreport.company_id = latest_report.company_id AND salesreport.periods = latest_report.max_periods
WHERE salesreport.periods <= 2016-01-01;
```

**update 2**

so i think after examining my query i find that there is something wrong about my query, so inside my join i do `MAX(periods)` and because of that it will always returning the highest value for those fields and the problem is i want to put a limit how high the value that i wanted to returning.

so maybe someone can think of other things to help me achieve this?

Comment: How would your exact sql statement look like if you did not have to use eloquent? Maybe if we know that, we can help you with a complete setup :)

Comment: i think it will be like that... i am not quite sure myself but please take a look at my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Ive done some research in my own code, as I needed this quite often, came up with this solution:

```
$data = App\SalesReport::with('company')->join(DB::RAW('(SELECT company_id, MAX(periods) AS max_periods FROM laporancu GROUP BY company_id) latest_report'),function($join){
    $join->on('salesreport.company_id','=','latest_report.company_id');
    $join->on('salesreport.periods','=','latest_report.max_periods');
})->where('periods','<=','2016-01-01')->FilterPaginateOrder();
```

Just let me know if this works. And if it does not, what error you are getting :)

Comment: it's not getting error by using this, but it will not return 2015 data even thought there is one in database. it just doing where clause in data that have been joined and grouped. what i trying to achive is get the data before doing grouping and join. the data with periods less than 2016 and after that grouping it and join it by the latest periods that less than 2016

Comment: Are there laporancu records with max_periods of 2015?

Comment: yes, not in max_periods but in periods, thats why i think i need to do where clause before doing groupBy and join so it will return all salesreport that have periods less than 2016 and after than then it will groupBy company and join by the latest periods that are less than 2016....

Comment: Maybe $data = App\SalesReport::with('company')->join(DB::RAW('(SELECT company_id, MAX(periods) AS max_periods FROM laporancu GROUP BY company_id) latest_report'),function($join){
    $join->on('salesreport.company_id','=','latest_report.company_id');
    $join->on('salesreport.periods','<','latest_report.max_periods');
})->FilterPaginateOrder(); ? (changed 2nd '=' to '<')

Answer (score 0):

after searching and asking around for help, i finally come with a solution that works just as what i needed so here is it:

```
$periods = '2016-01-01';
$data = App\SalesReport::with('company')->join(DB::RAW('(SELECT company_id, MAX(periods) AS max_periods FROM salesreport WHERE periods <= '$periods' GROUP BY company_id) latest_report'),function($join){
    $join->on('salesreport.company_id','=','latest_report.company_id');
    $join->on('salesreport.periods','=','latest_report.max_periods');
})->where('periods','<=','2016-01-01')->FilterPaginateOrder();
```

hope it helps anyone in future who wanted to do the similar query like me